# jQuery .click odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element by clicking on which some function is called by jQuery .click method. There is a condition in the body of the function. When I click on an element one time at a time everything runs smoothly, but if I click two times quickly the condition, which is supposed to stop a function, doesn't run, and the function is executed two times instead of one. So it is as if clicks are being accumulated. How can I prevent this behaviour of a .click method?

```
$(".collections_pager_right").click(function() {
    if (collections_wrapper_left > 0 - collections_wrapper_width + 770) {
        $(".collections_slider_wrapper").animate({left: "-=770"}, 400);
    };
});
```

Comment: Maybe try `$(".collections_slider_wrapper").stop().animate({left: "-=770"}, 400);`

Comment: have you considered : http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: What are the variables in the condition?

Comment: Tyagi: I think dlclick would eliminate the problem, but I wouldn't like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a attribute like running="false" in your element, so after that you can check it.

```
$(".collections_pager_right").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('running') == 'false'){
     $(this).attr('running','true');
     if (collections_wrapper_left > 0 - collections_wrapper_width + 770) {
        $(".collections_slider_wrapper").animate({left: "-=770"}, 400, function(){
          $(this).attr('running','false');               
        });
     };
    }
});
```